# Guest VM in Virtualbox connected to a vpn while the host machine is not?

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, virtualbox

Is it possible to have a guest VM in Virtualbox connected to a vpn while the host machine is not? If so, what specific network adapter configurations do I need to setup/add in the virtual box vm settings?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible, I do it every single day for work (I have several VPN programs and configs in my VM, and I use them to connect to client's networks).

From my point of view (and my current VM config in VirtualBox), there's no specific network adapter needed. My VM is using the default NAT adapter and I can connect to VPNs just fine with it.